# Browser claims JS function is 'not defined,' but if I run it from the command line it works

Tags: javascript, function, call, scope

I'm just getting started with Javascript, trying to build a Jeopardy game, and I'm trying to call a function from within another function. On my site, you click this button:

```
<input type="button" value="Build My Jeopardy! Game" onclick="drawBoard()">
```

Which runs this function:

```
function drawBoard() {

    formtoVariables();

    document.getElementById('body').innerHTML = '<center><h1>Jeopardy!</h1><div id="screen"><table id="board"><thead><td id="cat1" value="cat1"></td><td id="cat2"></td><td id="cat3"></td><td id="cat4"></td><td id="cat5"></td></thead><tr><td id="r1c1"></td><td id="r1c2"></td><td id="r1c3"></td><td id="r1c4"></td><td id="r1c5"></td></tr><tr><td id="r2c1"></td><td id="r2c2"></td><td id="r2c3"></td><td id="r2c4"></td><td id="r2c5"></td></tr><tr><td id="r3c1"></td><td id="r3c2"></td><td id="r3c3"></td><td id="r3c4"></td><td id="r3c5"></td></tr><tr><td id="r4c1"></td><td id="r4c2"></td><td id="r4c3"></td><td id="r4c4"></td><td id="r4c5"></td></tr><tr><td id="r5c1"></td><td id="r5c2"></td><td id="r5c3"></td><td id="r5c4"></td><td id="r5c5"></td></tr></table></div></center>';

    fillBoardWithText();

};
```

The problem I'm running into is with formToVariables() - the browser gives me this error:

> ReferenceError: formtoVariables is not defined

However, if I open up the console in Chrome and type

```
formToVariables();
```

the function runs. I think this issue might be related to scope - I can call formToVariables() myself, but drawBoard() doesn't have access to it for some reason. Any idea why that might be? Or is the problem related to something else?

Comment: You really haven't posted enough code. Where is the "formtoVariables" function defined? It's certainly a scope error, but exactly what the problem is cannot be determined precisely without more of your code being available.

Answer (score 3):

Your t is lowercase instead of capital:

```
formtoVariables();
```

Should be:

```
formToVariables();
```

Since Javascript is case-sensitive those are two different function names. The second is defined, the first is not.

Comment: This was the problem - all fixed now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is case sensitive.  `formToVariables` != `formtoVariables`.